# How to change the type of "open file" prompt in Internet Explorer

Tags: ms-word, internet-explorer-11

I have a .Net web application that allows the user the open a Word document which is a macro-based report. This has worked well for years until recently. And now we are starting to have some issues with the opening of the Word doc.

I've determined that I currently have some PCs that work well, and some that don't. Here are the main differences:

**Working:**

- When clicking on the file link, the IE11 browser shows a prompt on the center of the screen asking the user to "open, save or cancel". Similar to this:
  [image: Good]
- When the user selects "Open", the word file is opened with a yellow message saying "Enable content".
- When the user clicks on "Enable content", the macro executes and the data is filled correctly.

**Not working**:

- When clicking on the file link, the IE11 browser shows a prompt on the bottom of the screen asking the user to "open, save or cancel". Like this:
  [image: Fail]
- When the user selects "Open", the word file is opened with a yellow message saying "Enable edit".
- When the user selects "Enable edit", there is a new yellow message saying "Enable content".
- When the user clicks on "Enable content", the macro does not execute and/or has no data.

So my questions are, What's the difference in the IE11 setup and how do I change it?
Oh... company policy forces me to use IE, I have no other choice.

Comment: Are the same versions of Word installed on all these machines? I believe IE executes Word, and newer versions of Word behave differently than older versions...

Comment: Yes, it's the same version in all cases: IE11, Office 2010.

Comment: I suspect this is an IE configuration issue, at least in part (the open/save/cancel interface) and perhaps a Word Trust Center issue, in addition (the yellow bar and whether the macro runs). So StackOverflow, which is primarily for coding questions, is probably not the optimal place to ask. In your place, I might try the Word IT Pro forum on the TechNet site (microsoft.com).

Comment: The other suggestion would be to look at File/Options/Trust Center/Trust Center Settings and compare two user profiles that work / don't work. If you find discrepancies, and changing the settings makes a difference, a Group Policy could bring all company installations into alignment...

Comment: I had already compared those settings and didn't find any differences. I will check the forums you have suggested. Thanks.